# Is there a method in react native to persistently display the badge count, even after all notifications have been cleared or dismissed on android?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

I aim to maintain the badge count even after all notifications have been cleared or dismissed. Despite utilizing 'setApplicationIconBadgeNumber' to set the badge, it disappears when notifications are cleared. Is there an alternative approach or solution to ensure the badge remains visible?